# access value of JSON by key using ajax doesn't display result

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have a JSON data looking like this (it's not an object, it's an array):

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
  }
]
```

and a function to get data and display it using AJAX, I use JSON.parse() to get the JSON from string:
Initialize a XMLHttpRequest object:

```
let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
```

Add a new element to the document:

```
var table='<tr><th>Name</th><th>Email</th></tr>';
        table += '<tr><td>' +
            jsonObj["name"] +
            '</td><td>' +
            jsonObj["email"] +
            '</td></tr>'
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = table;
    }
};
```

But when I run the browser doesn't display value in the table field, it shows **undefined**. Is there something wrong? I also changed to use JSON.stringtify(), but the result still didn't change. Please help me to figure out the problem

Comment: What happens when you `console.log(jsonObj);` after you `JSON.parse` it?

Comment: Your json data is an array. So, you should show it in the loop. Like as
`for (var item of jsonObj) {  table += item.name }...`

Comment: _"(it's not an object, it's an array)"_ - An array in JavaScript is also an object, just run `typeof []`

Comment: if there is not '[' at begin and end, is JSON data above still an array to loop over?

Comment: If there is not "[]" it is not an array, and loops will not work porperty.

Answer (score 1):

You should a loop to iterate the array like @Lee Taylor said.

```
for (var item of jsonObj) {
    table += "<td>" + item.name + "</td>"
}
```